# JPA - Can't insert into a table with a defined type (Oracle)

Tags: java, jpa, insert, eclipselink, varray

I have the following problem: in my database there is a table that uses a defined type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ARRAY_METHODS IS VARRAY (10) OF NUMBER (2);
```

This column is mapped as `List<BigDecimal>` in its respective entity. The problem starts when I try to do an insert with JPA (I tried both `persist()` and `merge()`). Looking for a solution I found that I have to add the `@Array` and `@Struct` annotations:

```
@Entity
@Struct(name="ARRAY_METHODS")
@Table(name="MY_TABLE")

...

@Array(databaseType="ARRAY_METHODS")
@Column(name="METHODS")
private List<BigDecimal> methods;
```

But It still fails:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported Feature
Error Code: 17023
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.myproject.models.MyTable@45c242ae)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.throwRollbackException(TransactionImpl.java:1878)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:359)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.commit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:250)at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.postInvoke1(BaseLocalObject.java:336)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.__WL_postInvokeTxRetry(BaseLocalObject.java:205)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseWSLocalObject.__WL_postInvokeTxRetry(BaseWSLocalObject.java:194)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.WSOMethodInvoker.invoke(WSOMethodInvoker.java:40)
    at com.myproject.ops.OpPhysicalResourcePortTypeImpl_14p9mm_WSOImpl.__WL_opAltaRecurso(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at weblogic.wsee.server.ejb.WsEjb.invoke(WsEjb.java:54)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSEjbInstanceResolver$WLSEjbInvoker.invoke(WLSEjbInstanceResolver.java:196)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:420)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:687)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:205)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:634)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:108)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:278)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:287)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:134)
    at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3363)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
```

Working with: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition, JDK 7, Oracle Weblogic 12c

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting with Oracle, they say the problem is that inserting in a numeric array is not allowed. So now we hava a new table.

Answer (score 0):

Is it crucial to have in the same table? solution could to use @ElementCollection instead @Array

Comment: It's not crucial, but I'm working in this project and I'm not free to change the model. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion but it still doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, you are suing EclipseLink 2.4.2, have you tried newer versions of it?

Comment: Yes, 2.5 and same error. With `@ElementCollection` now I get `Caused By: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SERGI"."MY_TABLE"."METHODS")`. Looking at the query I see that the column doesn't appear in it.

Comment: With `@ElementCollection` you do not need `@Column`. See example  [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection)

Comment: Also it strage that it says about `NULL`, try to initialize your array (like new `ArrayList<BigDecimal>`)